Interpolating Temperature Raster Stack containing NAs
I have a raster stack of approximately 50 layers. This raster stack contains day land surface temperature over a period of three years across a 500km2 area. The data is from MODIS Terra MOD11A2 v061. Some raster layers contain NAs. However, this is a problem as I want to match household coordinates with the correct raster both spatially and temporally and extract temperature data.
I was wondering what the best approach is to statistically fill in these NA's. From some reading I have done, Spatio-Temporal Kriging appears to be a good option that is not too computationally intensive.
I wanted to know what people's thoughts are on this and how to do this in R.
Many thanks and look forward to your insights.
